Trouver la fonction (COI ou CCL ?)
Dans la phrase

Éric écrit un mot sur une feuille

quelle est la fonction de « sur une feuille » ?
Je pensai au départ à un complément circonstanciel de lieu. Mais on m'a fait observer que cela signifierais qu'Éric est lui-même debout sur la feuille !
Ce serait alors plutôt un COI. Mais en recherchant sur internet je ne trouve pas de règle claire, et je me demande si c'est finalement un CCL ou un COI...
Qu'en pensez-vous ?

Très bonne question.
Je prends le parti du Complément Circonstanciel de Lieu. Et ce pour 3 raisons:

Le Complément d'Objet peut bien être introduit par une préposition, mais il est typiquement essentiel dans la phrase visée, e.g. je prends mon bain; tu passes au milieu de terrain; elle roule des mécaniques. La phrase n'a pas de sens/le même sens sans. Ce qui n'est pas le cas du CC (Eric écrit un mot est une phrase correcte/complète; il peut l'écrire où il veut, ça reste de la "décoration").

Les compléments dont on parle, et circonstanciels en particulier, décrivent l'action via le verbe. Le rôle du sujet est secondaire. Ce dernier n'aurait pas posé problème dans la phrase Eric écrit un mot dans sa chambre, où dans sa chambre est aussi un CCL, car le sujet Eric est bien localisé dans sa chambre. Mais ce fait concernant le sujet n'est à mon sens pas une nécessité pour identifier un complément de verbe/CC, orienté action. Les compléments du nom sont, eux, centrés sur le nom auquel ils se rapportent. On peut dire que le CCL dans la phrase initiale précise la localisation du résultat de l'action d'écriture, tandis que la phrase précédente précise le lieu du processus d'écriture. Dans les deux cas il s'agit d'un aspect du verbe.

Les compléments dont on parle répondent (en utilisant donc le verbe) à une question. Le CCL répond à la question "où?". Or la question "écrit où?" est correcte pour avoir la réponse "sur une feuille". C'est un CC.


